# How do I transfer data from my Windows 7 computer to my Windows 8 Phone?

Tags: sync, usb

I have a HTC 8s phone. I have an 8GB SD Card inserted into my mobile.

How do I transfer data (music/videos/images) from my Windows 7 computer to my Windows 8 Phone (HTC 8s) ?

I have tried and installed : http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop

But it never shows my phone as connected, below is the screenshot :

[image]

and when I connect my phone using USB, I get the following errors :

[image]

[image]

I have all that I could, please some one help me out on this one. Do I need to install some HTC drivers or some other driver ?

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you plug your phone in prior to installing the Windows Phone application?

Comment: yes. Could that be the problem ? I have also rebooted my machine and my phone a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your driver for USB devices supporting Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) is not working as expected (in theory, you *should* [be able to see the phone pop up in Windows Explorer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/start/..%5Cstart%5Cmove-music-photos-and-videos-between-my-computer-and-my-phone)).

The [HTC website](http://www.htc.com/uk/support/howto.aspx?p_id=540&id=301682&p_name=windows-phone-8s-by-htc) suggests that you *should* just be able to plug the phone in, and it will do the right thing. As you installed the software "in advance" it may be that the drivers won't install properly - it may be worth uninstalling the software, and any partially installed drivers - they'll show in device manager (Go to Start > Computer, then right-click Computer > Properties > Device Manager) with an icon if something isn't quite right. I'd recommend a reboot, then once you've logged back on, connect the phone and see if it is happier that way around. If not, then I'd suggest dropping [HTC Support a line](http://www.htc.com/uk/contact/phone/) and let them know the steps you've taken to try and troubleshoot the issue.