# How similiar is a lumia and a android (galaxy s3 ) in terms of file transfering?

Tags: lumia, android

I'm thinking of getting myself a new smartphone and the windows phone caught my attention. I gave one to my mother (lumia 720) and she loved it. I never used one myself though.

One of the things i like of my s3, is the fact that i don't have to use a single software to add music, videos, photos or whatever. Just plug it with an usb cable and transfer the files. This is one of the reasons i've never got an iphone.I have itunes.

Do you have to use any software to transfer files to a windows phone (the lumia series to be more precise)?

Oh, and which lumia is similar or better than a S3?

Answer (score 5):

Which is better is such a personal decision, and I'd always recommend playing with a real device to see if it would work *for you*.

Instead, and sticking to the facts, I'll focus on transferring data to/from your phone, which is dead simple - the phone appears as a "MTP USB Device", and it "just works" (at least, with Windows 8, or 8.1 - I've not tried with other versions, or other operating systems). There is a [desktop application for at least Windows 7](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1372/106) as well, but it isn't *required* to transfer files.

On Windows 8, the PC will suggest you install the "Windows Phone" app, which can automatically syncs bits, but you don't *require* it - you can just as easily copy files with Explorer, Windows Media Player, etc.

Of course, over and above transferring files via USB, there is strong links with OneDrive (née SkyDrive, née LiveDrive...), and you can automatically set photos taken, documents written, etc. to sync and be available from more or less anywhere you need to get your hands on them.

Comment: Hmm...i see. I'll try to test drive one of the Lumia phones. I used my mother's for a while and i liked it. One of the things that is motivating me on getting a windows phone is that i'm a .net developer, and i could try to make an app or two later on. By the way, from a galaxy s3, which lumia should be similar or better (in terms of hardware)?

Comment: The desktop application isn't required on Windows 7 either

Comment: @akid thanks, I've updated accordingly :)

Comment: @JoaoVictor Sounds like you're happy with the OS from using your mother's; so it then depends on what matters most to you - ability to use an SD card (so maybe a Lumia 820), ability to take [awesome pictures](http://www.nokia.com/global/red-bull-lumia-photos/) (so maybe a Lumia 1020) or whether you want a massive (well, 6") screen (so maybe a Lumia 1520). The [Nokia website](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/phones/lumia/) allows you to compare their models (of course, other manufacturers *do exist*)

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.getsync.com/) on your computer and on your phone. It supports all major platforms. Requires no payment, no accounts, no hassle, and how this works is:

1. Create directories (Read & Write access) on your PC that will be synced with the mobile device.
2. Scan the generated QR code with your phone's BitTorrent Sync app, and direct it to the folder you want to sync
3. Profit

This way I've synced my photos, screenshots, scanned documents (so that I'd have them on my phone when on trips). All I do is copy them to a folder on my PC, and they will automatically sync with my phone. When on the same network on WiFi, it will sync over the network (no internet traffic there). Otherwise it will sync over the internet.

Very fast, very reliable. It's like Drobox and such, but free, and without online storage.

Check out this video that presents some possibilities: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRrfZmBUS0A

Comment: Isn't relevant. He's asking if you have to use any software.

Comment: If he has to, it might be this as well. You must admit it's at least half relevant.