# Cannot connect phone to PC due to missing driver

Tags: nokia-lumia-620, windows-7

I have a PC running Windows 7 Home Basic. I used to be able to connect my Lumia 620 to it just fine, but now I'm no longer able to. When I connect the phone to the PC, I'm not able to browse its contents. I've tried the troubleshooter and it's saying that some driver needs to be installed.

What driver do I need?

Comment: Dont you need that software that replaces Zune when you are using Windows 7?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Not according to akid on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3909/106

Answer (score 1):

The drivers should just self install - it may be that they've become corrupted on your PC. One thing you can do, whilst the phone is connected, is to go into (from memory, as I don't have a Windows 7 PC to hand) Control Panel -> Device Manager - If you have any with a yellow warning triangle, right click and choose "Uninstall" - if you don't have any with a warning triangle, look for devices under "Universal Serial Bus devices" and uninstall the phone (it may just show as a MTP device). Then disconnect your phone, reboot, and once logged back on, reconnect your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Set automatically get recommended drivers and updates for your hardware (Windows Update). And try remove and reinstall drivers for your phone

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware

Answer (score 0):

In your PC/Laptop, with your phone still connected

> Go to Device Manager >> Portable Devices >> *Your Phone's Name* >> Uninstall *(on right-click)*

And

> Go to Device Manager >> Universal Serial Bus Devices >> Uninstall *(every single one of them)*

And then connect your phone again to install the drivers from the scratch.